# How to sort an array of non-english (Slovanian) words in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a string composes of Slovenian characters such as (žiga, špela, črt, ...) and i need to sort this string alphabetically, the problem i want to do that using loops only without using any builtin function in .NET like `array.Sort()`.

```
static string[] SortByName(string[] fullname)
{
    char[] abc =
    {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'č', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'š','t', 'u', 'v', 'z', 'ž'
    };

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<abc.Length;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < fullname[counter].Length; j++)
        {
            // I still cant figure out what i can do here 
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with creating a `Comparer` and use `Sort`?

Comment: @Omar try using culture `Array.Sort(abc, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: it is an assignment and only allowed to use loops not more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, the `char` array `abc` stores all the Slovenian alphabets in order. You can use this array as a reference to the ranks of all the Slovene alphabets to **compare** the Slovene words. In the code below, I have defined a method `CompareSl()` to compare Slovene words, just like the `Compare()` method of the `String` class compares English words.  (The method `index()` returns the index of a character in the array abc.)

> The **Compare()** method of the **String** class takes two strings **s1** and **s2** as arguments and
>   ♦ Returns 0 if the strings are equal
>   ♦ Returns (+)ve if **s1 > s2**
>   ♦ Returns (-)ve if **s1 < s2**

```
using System;

class Sl_Sort{    

    static void Main(){
        string[] words = new string[]{"žiga", "špela", "črt"};

        Console.WriteLine("Unsorted array is");
        foreach(String st in words)
            Console.Write(st+" , ");
        //do selection sort to sort in ascending order

        for(int i=0; i<words.Length-1;i++){
            int min = i;
            for(int j=i+1; j<words.Length;j++){
                if(CompareSl(words[min], words[j]) > 0)
                    min  = j;
            }
            string temp = words[i];  
            words[i] = words[min]; 
            words[min] = temp;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted array is");
        foreach(String st in words)
            Console.Write(st+" , ");
        Console.ReadKey(); //waits till user presses a key before terminating
    }

    public static int CompareSl(string s1, string s2){
        if(s1.Length == s2.Length){
            for(int i=0; i<s1.Length; i++){
                if(s1[i] != s2[i])
                    return index(s1[i]) - index(s2[i]);
            }
        }
        else{
            String s = s1.Length<s2.Length?s1:s2;
            for(int i=0; i<s.Length; i++){
                if(s1[i] != s2[i])
                    return index(s1[i]) - index(s2[i]);
            }
            if(s == s1)
            return -1;
            else
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static int index(char c){
        char[] abc = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'č', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'š', 't', 'u', 'v', 'z', 'ž' };
        for(int i=0; i<abc.Length; i++){
            if(abc[i]==c)
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Unsorted array is
ziga , spela , crt ,

Sorted array is
crt , spela , ziga
```

Note: The characters `ž`, `š` and `č` got converted to `z`, `s` and `c` respectively because the platform I ran the code on was not set to `UTF-8` or `Unicode`, which support Slovene, but `ANSI`, which does not support Slovene. Make sure your system supports Slovene to get the correct output.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
 private char[] charList = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'č', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 'š', 't', 'u', 'v', 'z', 'ž' };
public string[] Sort(string inputStr)
{
    string[] sortedChars = new string[inputStr.Length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < charList.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < inputStr.Length; u++)
        {
            sortedChars[index] = inputStr[u];
            index++;
        }
        if (index == inputStr.Length)
            return sortedChars;   
    }   
    return sortedChars;
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so not sure it works, but what it does is:
Iterate trough the chars, so it searches for "a" on each char of the inputString, if it's there it will be added to the sorted string[], then when it finishes with the first char, the next...etc.

Probably there's some error, maybe you can improve the code.

Comment: it didnt work , i ried to fix the code but still not working

Comment: Wow, I think I misunderstod your question completely. I was changing the code, but the code was to sort the characters on each string, like this: ziga->agiž. I feel so stupid now :P